# Where is the documentation source for python? (and spyder documentation features)

Tags: python, spyder

Where is the documentation kept for spyder (python IDE) to access?

As I am typing `plot.savefig(` in the spyder console, I get a pop up for the documentation for savefig(). It's a pretty nice feature, but it disappears as soon as I move the mouse. Where is it pulling this documentation from? I have searched the /doc folder and can't find anything related to matplotlib. I would like to open it in a PDF viewer on another monitor.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.savefig()
```

Here is an image of the documentation for clarification:

[image: Image of savefig doc]

Comment: Are you looking for this documentation, or for some other documentation? https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation that you're seeing comes from the docstrings of the function you typed in. You can get the raw text with `plt.savefig.__doc__`, or get it with a bit of formatting by using the builtin `help` command from an interactive interpreter: `help(plt.savefig)`. Spyder applies some additional fancy formatting to the contents of its documentation window.

How detailed the documentation is will vary quite a bit from module to module. In the case of `matplotlib`, it's quite detailed, probably because the maintainers have put the effort in to make it easy to use that package without a lot of programming experience.

As for your question about how you can view those docs outside of Spyder, I'd suggest looking online. I see on the `matplotlib` homepage they have extensive documentation, including [web pages with the same contents as the docs you were seeing](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) (presumably generated from the same docstrings).

Comment: Ah thanks for the background information on the __doc__ function. Ah the website is great. This isn't wasn't what I had in mind for the answer, but this is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder dev here*) The documentation you mean is the little yellow box next to `plt.savefig(`, right? These are called calltips and I fixed them in our next version (`2.3`, in release candidate now) so that they are maintained on screen if you put the mouse over them and hidden if you click on them or automatically after a certain time.

*Notes*:

1. This doesn't work in Spyder `2.2.5` or before.

About the documentation: We are planning to add tabs the Object Inspector so you can view several documentation pages at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This may be not relevant to you now but now you can use `?plt.savefig`. This will come handy for R users who are migrating to python on spyder because both follow same way to display documentation.